# Как при помощи CallbackQuery перейти на следующий state aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я запускаю state.

```
async def user_form_start(message : types.Message):
    try:
        query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT tg_id FROM bot WHERE tg_id = '" + str(message.from_user.id) + "' AND status = 1)"
        if (check_username(message.from_user.id, db_name, query)[0][0] == 1):
            await message.answer('Ваша заявка обрабатывается, дождитесь ответа')
        else:
            await Form.uni.set()
            await message.answer('Выберите из списка университет', reply_markup=btn_uni_select_kb)
    except:
        await message.answer('Что-то пошло не так, сообщения об ошибках обрабатываются мной максимально быстро')
```

Здесь обработчик, он находится в другом файле.

```
async def uni_button_select(query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if (len(get_arr_uni("uni.txt")) > parse_digit(query.data)):
        await state.update_data(uni=get_arr_uni("uni.txt")[parse_digit(query.data)])
        print(get_arr_uni("uni.txt")[parse_digit(query.data)])
```

В нем я обрабатываю и обновляю значение, как сделать так что при его срабатывании у меня state переходит на следующий. То есть при начале state отправляет inline кнопку, по нажатию на которую state сменяется на следующий. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то uni_button_select не ловит следующие состояние.
Всё потому что по дефолту там не установлено никакое состояние

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(state='*')
async def uni_button_select(query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if (len(get_arr_uni("uni.txt")) > parse_digit(query.data)):
        await state.update_data(uni=get_arr_uni("uni.txt")[parse_digit(query.data)])
        print(get_arr_uni("uni.txt")[parse_digit(query.data)])
```

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Form.uni) - можно так же сделать
```